# Forwarding request to Azure Application Gateway Backend Pool depending upon Incoming request header

Tags: azure, iis, azure-powershell, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

I have the following Setup:

1. One Application Gateway with WAF V2.
2. Two backend pools (say Backend1 and Backend2).
3. Both backends have same Application but with different version (Say
   V1 and V2).

I want the following scenarios to work:

- If a request coming to Application Gateway from client device had
  V1's info in its header, then the request should be forwarded to
  Backend1.
- If a request coming to Application Gateway from client device had
  V2's info in its header, then the request should be forwarded to
  Backend2.

Your help will be highly appreciate.

Note: I don't want port based backend forwarding of requests.

Comment: which kind of request header you want to match. in my opinion, by using iis it is not possible to forward a request to the application gateway pool.

Comment: Request will coming on Application Gateway public Ip from client device, the request header has User-Agent information which stores Application Version. Depending upon the User-Agent information, can we forward the traffic to the backend pool hosting the same version of Application.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Application Gateway does not support HTTP header based routing yet. You can upvote in [Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/37468165-add-functionality-to-application-gateway-for-routi) to implement the feature in future.